# i want two boxes at one page in one div

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website, but I have a problem.

I have one div that creates the content with a BG color!

The problem is, the text appears in line to the bottom but I want them next to each other!

Here is a link to a screenshot for an example:

http://www.mupload.nl/img/9x7jco1v45f.png

I've tried some code in my CSS but nothing worked.

This is what I have now:

CSS:

```css
#rechts {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#lings {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.inhoud {
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
    padding-top:150px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="inhoud">
    <p class="contactInhoudLings">

    // Here is the personal info.
    <p class="contactInhoudRechts">

    // here is the PHP Contact form.
    </p>
</div><!-- #inhoud -->
```

Comment: give us some code than we can better help you :)

Comment: Give us your html please

Comment: A general suggestion: stick to English when coding, that is the language that HTML and CSS and nearly all other languages are built with/for. It will be tremendously easier for anyone to understand your code if you use English.

Comment: Roope; thanks for the suggestion!! i have to agree with you... from now i will use English when coding!!

Comment: @Roope: The advice to stick to English is good only as long as English is a comfortable language for the OP (and any coding team members, present and anticipated). If the project in question is not open-source, then, IMHO, your advice becomes much less excellent than it first sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utilize `display:inline-block;` like below

```css
.container {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.section {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">
        Some random inforamtion here<br/>
        more contact information
    </div>
    <div class="section right">
        Name<br/>
        <input type="text" /><br/>
        Email<br/>
        <input type="text" /><br/>
        Phone<br/>
        <input type="text" /><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML you provided, simply change your css to

```
.contactInhoudLings{
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}

.contactInhoudRechts{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5pguvq6m/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flex` to split the container in two or any other number.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.col {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
        text
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        your form
 
        <form>
            <label for=name>Name:<label/>
            <input type=text name=name placeholder=name />
            <input type=submit />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `margin-left` and `margin-right` than try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="inhoud">
  <p class="contactInhoudLings">
   // Here is the personal info.
  <p class="contactInhoudRechts">
   // Here is the PHP Contact form.
  </p>
</div><!-- #inhoud -->
```

**CSS**

```
.inhoud{
  width: 100%;
}
.contactInhoudLings{
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
  width:49%;
}
.contactInhoudRechts{
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  width:49%;
}
```

Look also the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xb8ouu0b/) example

Comment: this almost works!!! my footer come up to the top almost... and my .inhoud  will not fill :(

Comment: @#$%^&* it... here is the link to the live version!!! http://reduankurtaj.eu/nieuw/contact.php